# Compiler Error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 (Mac OS X 10.10.4; GLM)

Tags: c++, macos, glm-math

i have implemented a new class SceneObject into my raytracer project. In this project I'm using the glm lib to do certain tasks.

Now I'm getting the: 
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64
Error when I try to compile.

My compiler:

```
 ✘ arneosterthun@Arnes-Air  ~/Documents/Studium/Programmiersprachen/raytracer/build   SceneObject ●  gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Configured with: ../gcc-4.9-20141029/configure --enable-languages=c++,fortran
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 20141029 (prerelease) (GCC) 
 arneosterthun@Arnes-Air  ~/Documents/Studium/Programmiersprachen/raytracer/build   SceneObject ●  make -v
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

This is a gist on github with my new implemented code and the full error message: https://gist.github.com/aosterthun/658c8cf6a691e9e5efbb

This is a link to the complete project on dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5kprshxumseguqp/AADi5dbcj5zVTBipt7pUVAyaa?dl=0

Comment: That gist link is broken.

Comment: Well it appears as if you do not compile the `sceneobject` implementation alongside the code that's using the type. Maybe you forgot to add the file to your target in CMake. Without seeing your `CMakeLists.txt`, no one will be able to help you.

Comment: Here is link to the complete project  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5kprshxumseguqp/AADi5dbcj5zVTBipt7pUVAyaa?dl=0